# Automatic form submit doesn't send data

Tags: php, jquery, forms

This is one file I'm using to automatically submit data to other file

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<form action="/site/downloadprint" method="post">
<textarea style="" id="file" name="file"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(e) {
   var html=$('#download').html(); 
   $('#file').val(html);
   $('#submit').click();
});

</script>


<div id="download">
some html
</div>
```

It open's www.mysite.com/site/downloadprint but it is blank. It works when I manually click on button

```
if(isset($_POST["file"]))
{
    $path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/temp/".mt_rand().".html";
    $file=fopen($path, 'w');
    fwrite($file, $_POST['file']);
    fclose($file);

    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
    readfile($path);

}
```

**EDITED**:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<form action="/site/downloadprint" method="post">
<textarea style="display:none;" id="file" name="file"></textarea>
</form>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(e) {
   var html=$('#download').html(); 
   $('#file').val(html).parents("form").submit();
});

    </script>
<div id="download">
some html
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form gets submitted right away. You need to delegate the submit until you've written the items to the field.

It is better to trigger the `submit` event on the `form` element, rather than trying to trigger `click` on the button. You can use [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) with [`submit()`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) to achieve that:

```
$(function() {  
    $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#file').val($('#download').html());
        $(this).parent('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried that at one point and stick to it but it doesn't work. It submits but nothing happens. It is working on localhost. Look at ma edited code

Comment: Your edit doesn't work because you're never triggering the function when the button is clicked, only when the DOM is ready... Where is `$('#downloaded')`?

Comment: It is there, My goal is to automatically get html from #download, put it in textarea and submit it. It is working, but other file doesn't recognize submitted form

Comment: What does it look like? What if you submit to a page that just outputs `$_POST['file']`?

Comment: nothing, blank, like it doesn't post anything. On localhost it is working, on online server doesn't. I dont know why